# Question regarding Boundary Conditions for Electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, boundary-conditions

[image: E field in boundary conditions]

When considering the boundary conditions for $E$ $fields$ of a infinite long sheet(in $xy$ plane)  ,the E field is given by $\dfrac{σ}{2ε_0}\hat{z}$  (if the test charge is above the sheet)
,it becomes $\dfrac{σ}{2ε_0}\hat{(-z)}$(if the charge is below the sheet) ,now this is the $E$ field due to the charged sheet ,the $E$ field is along the perpendicular direction regardless of the test charge being above (or) below the sheet.

Now my explanation for the equation for the change in E fields in perpendicular direction goes something like this .

Now as I travel from the bottom of the sheet to the top of the sheet my $Electric$ Field changes in direction ,this makes me kind of think that the sheet has done something to the E field experienced by the test charge .

So like in the case of displacement where the net change in position is given by **Change in position =Final position - Initial position**.

Change in E field as I go from a point below the sheet to a point above the sheet is given by

Change in E field = Final $E$ field ($E_{\bot}^{above}$)- Initial $E$ field($E_{\bot}^{below}$)

=$\dfrac{σ}{2ε_0}\hat{z}$-(-$\dfrac{σ}{2ε_0}\hat{z})$=$\dfrac{σ}{ε_0}\hat{z}$.

I hope that's correct .

Coming to the parallel component of $E$ field .

Now I don't know how the E field due to a charged infinte sheet can have a parallel component for $E$ field ,I mean isn't the $E$ field due to a infinite charged sheet only along the perpendicular direction ?

Comment: There's no issue for the parallel part, because for an infinite flat sheet of *uniform* charge both sides of that equation are zero.

Comment: Yeah I get that ,but why should the E field have a parallel part in the first place ,I mean the net E field is just along the perpendicular direction .

Comment: That's only true if the charge can move to cancel the parallel component as would be true in a conducting medium, but a dielectric that doesn't conduct currents can have nom+normal electric field lines

Comment: @Triatticus ,I don't understand what you mean by charges can be moved to cancel to the parallel field ,I am sorry if this is stupid .

Comment: That's the whole basis of the perpendicular field for conductors. If there is any nonzero parallel electric field, this will cause a force on the charges, so the charges move and adjust on the surface until there is no parallel component to the electric field (equivalent to the net force parallel to the surface on each charge is zero).